# Connect to a port using a generic kermit script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, kermit

I wrote the following in a `kermit` script to connect to my serial device:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kermit
set port /dev/ttyUSB8
set speed 115200
set carrier-watch off
set flow-control none
set prefixing all
set input echo on
```

It does the job pretty well. Now, I want to make this a generic script and would like to take the input from the user which port he wants to connect. So, I thought taking input as a commandline argument is the best way to do. And I modified the above in the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kermit
port_num="/dev/ttyUSB"+$1
set port port_num
set speed 115200
set carrier-watch off
set flow-control none
set prefixing all
set input echo on
```

But, I get the following error:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~/Scripts$ ./test.script 8
?Not a command or macro name: "port_num="/dev/ttyUSB"+$1"
File: /home/Scripts/test.script, Line: 2
port_num
?SET SPEED has no effect without prior SET LINE
"8" - invalid command-line option, type "kermit -h" for help
```

I tried replacing

```
port_num="/dev/ttyUSB"+$1
```

with

```
port_num="/dev/ttyUSB$1"
```

as well. Which didn't work either. I get the

```
user4@user-pc-4:~/Scripts$ ./test.script 8
?Not a command or macro name: "port_num="/dev/ttyUSB$1""
File: /home/Scripts/test.script, Line: 2
port_num
?SET SPEED has no effect without prior SET LINE
"8" - invalid command-line option, type "kermit -h" for help
```

There is an obvious flaw in my second script. How can I get the script to accept the user input and connect to the serial port using `kermit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are confusing shell scripts with kermit scripts. `kermit` uses a completely different language to the shell. It is described [here](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ckermit70.html). In particular, you can access the script's arguments with the syntax `\%1` for arg 1 and so on. So change your second line to

```
set port /dev/ttyUSB\%1
```

If your kermit is similar to mine (ckermit 9.0), then you must also run your script with an extra first argument `--`, for example:

```
./test.script -- 8
```

If you prefer not to do this, replace the first line with the absolute path to kermit and then you can use the `+` flag instead, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/kermit +
```

Comment: This worked! Mine runs without the `--`. i.e, `./test.script 8` worked for me. Is that because yours is a newer/different version?

Comment: I imagine so, though it might be a platform build option. I get the error message: *"8" - invalid command-line option,...*. It is a bit hard trying to find when this feature was added.